# Force URL::to('') to open in HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: laravel, https

I'm using Laravel for the first time and my new client just switched to HTTPS.

I'm finding a lot of mixed content errors in the console of his site due to files and images opening in HTTP instead of HTTPS.

I checked his config/app.php and he already has:

```
'url' => 'https://www.Domain.co',
```

But when I check the code, where there is a mixed content error, there is a  `URL::to('')` which is rendering the domain without https.

Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

These issues generally happen as a result of having a proxy in front of Laravel.

As a first point of call, ensure that your [trusted proxy configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) is correct. This will cause Laravel to trust the `X-Forwarded-Protocol` header, and intern to generate the correct `https` URLs.

If you can't get the proxy configuration working, you can always force `https` URL generation by adding this in your `AppServiceProvider`

```php
if($this->app->environment('production')) {
    \URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Update `map()` in RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function map(Router $router, Request $request)
    {

        $httpHost = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : "");
        $requestUri = (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "");
        $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$httpHost/$requestUri";

        redirect($actual_link)->send();

    }
```

Comment: the current map function is: public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

        $this->mapWebRoutes();

        //
    }
Should I just replace it with what you wrote?

Comment: @Robin: Yes and please check

Comment: Okay so just replaced it without any luck :/ I'm still getting the mixed content issue on the images